# Mobile First war file creation

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have created a new dummy MF project which i want to deploy on my production server.

I have declared the target server in "build settings and deploy target..." menu and then i cleaned & built the project. Also i clicked "build all environments" for the Application.

If i don't run my App on the local  development server, no war file is created.

What i want is to create a project, deploy the war with the configuration tool and then create and deploy Apps in this runtime (all on the production server, not the local dev).

Is it normal that no war file is created when i build for the production server?
Can i use the war that is produced when i run on the development server or there is wrong configuration in its files inside it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the WAR file that is created for the local development server on your production server, as long as the artifacts in server/conf are the same (e.g., authenticationConfig.xml).  The WAR file is only created in Studio if you use the "run on development server" option.

You could also [create the project WAR file using Ant](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/r_ant_tasks_deploy_projects.html).

Comment: The server/conf folder is in the project. So when you say "the same" do you mean that after creating the war i should not change the arifacts without redeploying the war?

Comment: That's correct.  For instance, if you had to use a different kind of authentication mechanism in your development environment than you use in production (resulting in changes to authenticationConfig.xml), or something like that.  Since the artifacts in server/conf go into the WAR, if you ever change those, the WAR must be rebuilt - otherwise, it doesn't.

Comment: i managed to create a war from eclipse using ant as you described above. I created a build.xml in my project and then ran it with ant. In build.xml i only changed the pathelement for worklight-ant-builder.jar to reflect my own path. I produced a war and from what i see it contains the same files as the war produced by dev server. web xml is the same too.